# Ceiling vent right next to wall. Ideas for grille cover?

Tags: vent, ducts, register

The typical size 10x4 won't work because the wall is right next to it on one side (see picture).

I can buy a smaller size but then the question is where do I screw in the second hole.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the 10 x 14 and cut edge off that goes up against the wall and then drill two holes in each of the long edges of the register close to the wall. Use two plastic anchors and screws there and then one of the regular screws that came with the register on the far end. Stay cool man.

Answer (score 0):

Any size that covers it, drill new holes at the corners. Use drywall anchors.